# rss feed and Search engine optimization alert

Tags: indexing, rss

//may this is duplicate

i am using rss feed for my website ,the rss feed is create from php and mysql dynamically;

i read that rss feed is help in indexing;

now,
my question is **how i know that search engine is indexed my pages  using my rss feed** 
so i only include new content in next rss feed;

Comment: Sorry but this is off-topic here, since its about Google indexing and not programming related. Also duplicate on Pro Webmasters which would be your best bet: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=rss+duplicate+is%3Aquestion

Comment: No programming at all... Off-topic